# I am not able to enable jQuery in theme settings

Tags: wp-admin, jquery, options

I have tried to - enable `Use jQuery` & then save changes.

But after saving changes, checkmark `Use jQuery` automatically unchecks itself.

I am not sure whats going on. Please help me here.

[image]

Comment: this is an issue specific to your particular theme. you may have better luck contacting the developers of your theme to fix it, as it's not a general WordPress problem.

Comment: Try to "reset to defaults". _Mystique_ hasn't been updated for a long time, but a major update is going to be released these days, and most likely this won't happen in the new version...

Comment: Would you please check out - http://eleetgeek.com/. It has same theme. But it has no issues with jQuery. :( Why my site is having problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments fo @OneTrickPony, I came to know that,

`Mystique hasn't been updated for a long time, but a major update is going to be released these days, and most likely this won't happen in the new version...`

So, I conclude that issue is coming from the Theme itself. ( Not sure, but from the comments of @Milo & @OneTrickPony )

So, I uninstalled & removed `mystique` theme & at last I installed other theme. I know this is not the exact solution. But I had no option.